# Visual Studio package cannot be debugged in VS 2017 RC

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-package

I have a VSIX package (extension) that works and can be debugged in VS 2013 and 2015. I have now adjusted the manifest to allow the package to be installed in VS 2017. However, it doesn't work there properly and I want to debug it.

I open the package project in VS 2015 and tell it to debug the package in VS 2017 RC with the usual command line switch `/rootsuffix Exp`. A clean VS 2017 instance starts, but the package is not installed in it so it cannot be debugged. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only practical way to add support for VS 2017 is to open and build your extension in VS 2017: [How to: Migrate Extensibility Projects to Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017). After the migration it should be easy to debug in VS 2017.

Comment: Indeed, that way debugging in VS 2017 works. Still, isn't that odd that it doesn't work the way I tried it first? For instance, opening the project in VS 2013 and debugging in 2015 is no problem.